# Issue in script execution on Mac machine using SauceLab

Tags: mobile-automation

I am working in software qa company and facing an issue in executing scripts on Saucelab.

I got below error while executing single script using Android device on SauceLab using Mac machine which is automated using Ruby language:

Error: unexpected response, code=200, content-type=""

Note: Same code works fine on Windows machine.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.